# How to change timezone in alembic for sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I am creating a FastApi web app and I want to change the timezone to UTC, the problem is whatever I put at the timezone line in the alembic.ini file it shows an error. I tried to check [Alembic tutorial](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file) it didn't help either because it is a little ambiguous to me how to change it.

The console always shows this error.

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
.
.
.
ERROR [alembic.util.messaging] Can't locate timezone: UTC
FAILED: Can't locate timezone: UTC
```

I want to make it shows UTC timezone always.

Comment: Which python version are you using? If it's less than 3.9, you might need to install a timezone database, by running `pip install "alembic[tz]"`

Comment: I am using python version 3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer there was a missing package called **tzdata**. It contains the info for all time zones. I used [Wikipedia's list of timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to get a prettified list for all the timezones